# how to find/filter the array element with the smallest positive difference

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter

Using Swift, I am trying to workout a complex array filter or sort and I am stuck. My array of integers can contain between 1 and 7 elements. Given a certain integer value (say X) which is not in the array, I would like to find the array element that gives the smallest difference between itself and X.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In **Swift 2** you can do it as a "one-liner" with functional-style
programming:

```
let numbers = [ 1, 3, 7, 11]
let x = 6

let closest = numbers.enumerate().minElement( { abs($0.1 - x) < abs($1.1 - x)} )!

print(closest.element) // 7 = the closest element
print(closest.index)   // 2 = index of the closest element
```

`enumerate()` iterates over all array elements together with the
corresponding index, and `minElement()` returns the "smallest"
`(index, element)` pair with respect to the closure.
The closure compares the absolute values of the difference of
two elements to `x`.

(It is assumed here that the array is not empty, so that `minElement()`
does not return `nil`.)

Note that this is probably not the fastest solution for large arrays,
because the absolute differences are computed twice for (almost) all
array elements. But for small arrays this should not matter.

**Swift 3**:

```
let numbers = [ 1, 3, 7, 11]
let x = 6
let closest = numbers.enumerated().min( by: { abs($0.1 - x) < abs($1.1 - x) } )!
print(closest.element) // 7
print(closest.offset) // 2
```

The **Swift 1.2** version can be found in the edit history.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. Actually my elements don't exceed 7 but I am still using Swift 1.2. I would really appreciate it if you could include a Swift 1.2 functional-style solution.

Comment: @chronos: Do you need the closest value only or do you need the index as well?

Comment: The index is the main thing I need.

Comment: @chronos: See update. Note that Xcode 7 is final now, so spending too much time on Swift 1.2 code is perhaps not worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks, just updating to Xcode 7. This might not be exactly related to the question but I've watched the WWDC 2015 video on What's New In Swift and it basically scratches the surface. Do you know of any resource that gives in-depth info mainly on new functions in Swift 2?

Answer (score 7):

Building on Martin R's correct answer from a while ago, here's a handy extension I've been using. Currently in Swift 5.

```
extension Array where Element: (Comparable & SignedNumeric) {

    func nearest(to value: Element) -> (offset: Int, element: Element)? {
        self.enumerated().min(by: {
            abs($0.element - value) < abs($1.element - value)
        })
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let numbers = [ 1, 3, 7, 11]
let x = 6

if let closest = numbers.nearest(to: x) {
    print(closest)
}
// prints (offset: 2, element: 7)
```

Comment: How would we achieve this if we wanted to compare to a property of the array element?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

Not exactly what the OP is asking, but you can use the `first(where:)` and `firstIndex(where:)` array methods on a sorted array to get the first value greater than x:

```
let numbers = [1, 3, 7, 11]

let x = 6
let index = numbers.firstIndex(where: { $0 >= x })!
let result = numbers.first(where: { $0 >= x })!

print(index, result) // 2 7
```

Comment: This answer was useful for me (thanks!), but downvoting because it's actually not the answer to the question. They asked for the closest number, not the next one in the series. Proof for that is if `x = 4`, then `result == 7` which is not the closest number

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the values in your array, calculate the abs() difference, compare it to a running 'currentSmallestDifference' variable, if the current difference is smaller than that then overwrite it with the new value, at the same time keep a record of the array index...

```
int currentSmallestDifference = int.max(); //largest value defined by the int type, this way the first difference in the loop will never be larger than this 
int index = -1;   
for(int i = 0, i < array.size(), i++){
    if( abs(array(i) - X) < currentSmallestDifference){
        currentSmallestDifference = abs(array(i) - X);
        index = i;
    }
}
```

This solves it in O(n).

**But if the array was *already* sorted (O(nlog(n)), you could then do a O(log(n)) binary search for X in the array and find the closest value to it. No need to use abs() at all in that case... just comparisons**

But for array sizes 1 to 7, algorithmic complexity isn't really a factor.

In fact for array size 1, the *question* isn't even a factor (?!?)

***Update>>*** Just realised the title said smallest *positive* difference..  So just ditch all the abs() stuff and make sure (array(i) - X) is in the correct sign/direction.

Comment: I think it's better to make `currentSmallestDifference` an optional than to use `999999999` or some other constant.

Comment: ... or initialize with `Int.max`.

Comment: Int.max is what I had in mind, I just didn't know such a thing would be accepted in the parlance of psuedocode...

Comment: @LamarLatrell: I really meant `Int.max`, which is not pseudocode but real working Swift code. It returns the largest possible value for the `Int` type. Your `int.max()` does not compile.

Comment: oooh, ok - so hrrrrm, I see the tag in the original question *now*  :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to use the `reduce` method

```
let numbers = [1, 3, 7, 11]
let x = 11

let result = numbers.reduce(numbers.first!) { abs($1 - x) < abs($0 - x) ? $1 : $0 }
```

If you want to avoid repeated calculation of the absolutes, you could first map every array element to it's absolute difference from the input number and then find the minimum.

```
let numbers = [1, 3, 7, 11]
let x = 11

if let (index, _) = numbers.map({ abs($0 - x) }).enumerate().minElement({ $0.1 < $1.1 }) {
    let result = numbers[index]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped this into an extension:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: SignedNumeric & Comparable {

    /// Finds the nearest (offset, element) to the specified element.
    func nearestOffsetAndElement(to toElement: Iterator.Element) -> (offset: Int, element: Iterator.Element) {

        guard let nearest = enumerated().min( by: {
            let left = $0.1 - toElement
            let right = $1.1 - toElement
            return abs(left) <= abs(right)
        } ) else {
            return (offset: 0, element: toElement)
        }

        return nearest
    }

    func nearestElement(to element: Iterator.Element) -> Iterator.Element {
        return nearestOffsetAndElement(to: element).element
    }

    func indexOfNearestElement(to element: Iterator.Element) -> Int {
        return nearestOffsetAndElement(to: element).offset
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does a single loop that calculates the closest positive value.  Not a one-liner.  But still effective

```
let values = [1, 4, 9, 3, 8, 2, 11]
let x = 8

func closestPositiveValue(from array: [Int], value: Int) -> (Int, Int) { // -> (value, difference)
  var (val, dif): (Int?, Int?) = (nil, nil)
  for index in 0..<array.count {
    if x <= array[index] {
      var difference = x - array[index]
      if difference < 0 {
        difference = array[index] - x
      }
      if val == nil { // nil check for initial loop
        (val, dif) = (array[index], difference)
      } else {
        if difference < dif! {
          (val, dif) = (array[index], difference)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return (val ?? 0, dif ?? 0) // defaults to first item in array if there is no closest positive number
}
print(closestPositiveValue(from: values, value: x)) // prints (8, 0)
```