# How to find the dictionary value with the smallest difference from x [Swift]

Tags: swift, dictionary, enumeration

Using Swift, I am trying to workout a complex filter or sort that's the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568397/how-to-find-filter-the-array-element-with-the-smallest-positive-difference), but instead for a **dictionary** and it's values as opposed to an array. My values of integers can also be any integer value-- no restriction. Given a certain integer value (say X) which is not in the array, I would like to find the array element that gives the smallest difference between itself and X:

```
let playerGuesses = ["Mike": 432, "Chrissy": 164]
let x = 222
```

The answer given for the array version is as follows:

```
let closest = numbers.enumerated().min( by: { abs($0.1 - x) < abs($1.1 - x) } )!
print(closest.element) // 7
print(closest.offset) // 2
```

How do I accomplish something similar for dictionary values?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your question, I get the correct result using almost identical code (dropping the `enumerated().` from the calculation, then using `closest.key` and `closest.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same. Just drop `enumerated()` and use `key` and `value` with `closest`.

```
let playerGuesses = ["Mike": 432, "Chrissy": 164]
let x = 222
let closest = playerGuesses.min { abs($0.1 - x) < abs($1.1 - x) }
print(closest?.key, closest?.value)
```

Inside the `min` closure, `$x.0` is the key and `$x.1` is the value.

Comment: Perfect thanks @rmaddy! Follow up question: how do I grab the difference between each of the guesses (dictionary values) and the actual answer (x)?

Comment: That's a separate question. Try some things. Then, if needed, post a new question. Start with `map`.

Comment: Fair enough, I like your style. Thanks again!